# Is there an on click event without using JavaScript?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

CSS:

```
.tab div {
    display: none;
}

.tab div:target {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
}
.c {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: yellow;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

BODY:

```
<div class="tab">

<a href="#link1">Link 1</a>   
<a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#link3">Link 3</a>

<div id="link1">
  <h3>Content to Link 1</h3>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>

<div id="link2">
  <h3>Content to Link 2</h3>
  <h4>Great success!</h4>
</div>

<div id="link3">
  <h3>Content to Link 3</h3>
  <p>Yeah!</p>
</div>

<div class="c" style="display:block"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z9v4py3c/

I am thinking is there an any way: when I click on "a element", div with "c" class disappear. I tried a lot of options, but I am not a CSS expert. In this code "input element" cannot appear or JavaScript. I will be very thankful for help.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy and move `div.c` to `id="link#"`: https://jsfiddle.net/z9v4py3c/1/

Comment: Thank you for answer but when I enter on the website I want to "yellow div" be visible.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could find to do this was to fake it.

CSS: Only target the parent divs inside .tab and make the background white.

```
.tab > div {
    display: none;
    background:white;
}
```

HTML: Wrapped c in spans

```
<span><div class="c" style="display:block"></div></span>
```

Now when a link is active it simply hides the yellow under the white.

See my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z9v4py3c/)